# QGIS How change line thickness for multiple layers without changing their individual settings?

Tags: qgis, symbology, line

I want to change the line thickness for multiple layers with gpx tracks without changing their individual settings like their color.

I know I can copy one style and paste it to all selected layers but this overrides also their individual settings like their color.

Comment: Yes they should have all the same new thickness

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use this script for single symbol line layers:

```py
layers = iface.layerTreeView().selectedLayers()
for layer in layers:
    layer.renderer().symbol().setWidth(0.86)
    layer.triggerRepaint()
    iface.layerTreeView().refreshLayerSymbology(layer.id())
```

1. Change the number in `.setWidth(0.86)` to the line thickness you want
2. Select the layers you want to change in the layers panel
3. Run it from the python console

*The script does not work if you dont use lines or dont have a single symbol symbology, like a categorized renderer, applied.*

Comment: I've tried this code, but I get the following error: 

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS31~1.14\apps\Python39\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 5, in <module>
AttributeError: 'QgsFillSymbol' object has no attribute 'setWidth'`

Why is that? I'm obviously an absolute newby to PyQGIS ;)

Comment: @JesúsPinilla this code only works for line strings. lines cannot have a fill symbol.